# Manipulating a factorial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

How do I convert $\dfrac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots2n}{n!}$ to $(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)$?

I don't understand how the $n + x$ terms have appeared in this equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can simplify as follow

$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=\frac{\color{red}{1\cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot n} \cdot (n+1) \cdot ... \cdot 2n}{\color{red}{1\cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot n}}= (n+1) \cdot ... \cdot 2n$$

Comment: is this also true for (1 * 2 * 3 . . . *(2n-1) * 2n)/n! ?

Comment: @IskKander Note that $(1 * 2 * 3 . . . *(2n-1) * 2n)=(2n)!$ to be not confused with $2\cdot n!=2(1*2*...*n)=2*4*...*2n$.

Comment: Which terms are you canceling in this equation? I don't understand how the n!/n! were separated leaving the (n+1)....2n result.

Comment: @IskKander The red terms are those canceled. Try with some small number to see well how it works, for example fro $n=3$ we have $$\frac{1*2*3*4*5*6}{1*2*3}=4*5*6$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write : 
$$\begin{align}
1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (2n) &= (1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1))\cdot(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n))\\ &= (1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1))\cdot 2^n\cdot(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n)\\ &= (1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1))\cdot 2^n\cdot n!
\end{align}$$

Note that this goes beyond the question, as it shows that you can rewrite the product in a certain ways which suits your question situation. The "other" answer better suits the need of the problem.

Comment: That is true, but not what what was asked.